# Regex for splitting document

Tags: python, regex

I would like to split individual PDF documents from a compound set from a file. So far it works for files which are structured: `%PDF- .... %%EOF ... %PDF- .... %%EOF` by using the following code:

```
REGEX_PDF = b'%PDF\-.+?%%EOF'
pdfDocuments = re.findall( REGEX_PDF, fileContent, re.DOTALL )
```

Now I need to change the software to also work with PDFs with extensions. This results in a file structure like this: `%PDF- .... %%EOF ... %%EOF ... %%EOF ... %PDF- .... %%EOF`. So I need to match to substrings from a PDF tag until the last %%EOF tag before the next PDF tag. My best guess is this:

```
REGEX_PDF = b'%PDF\-.+(?!%PDF\-).+%%EOF'
```

But it does not seem to work. Instead only 1 substring is matched from the 1st %PDF tag top the very last %%EOF tag. Does someone has an idea where the error is?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on the `start delimiter here, and use

```py
re.split(rb'(?!\A)(?=%PDF-)', fileContent)
re.findall(rb'%PDF-.*?(?=%PDF-|\Z)', fileContent, re.S)
re.findall(rb'%PDF-[^%]*(?:%(?!PDF-)[^%]*)*', fileContent)
```

See the [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/H5Dq7w/1/), [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/H5Dq7w/2) and [regex #3 demo](https://regex101.com/r/H5Dq7w/3).

The `(?!\A)(?=%PDF-)` regex matches a location at a non-start position that is immediately followed with `%PDF-`.

The `%PDF-.*?(?=%PDF-|\Z)` pattern matches `%PDF-`, then any zero or more chars as few as possible up to the leftmost occurrence of `%PDF-` or end of string. `%PDF-[^%]*(?:%(?!PDF-)[^%]*)*` is almost the same, but it does not check if there is `%PDF-` on the right side (here, the `(?=%PDF-|\Z)` lookahead check is built ("married") into the `.*?` pattern).